# Separate command line into separate const char *

Tags: c++, command-line, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a Server application right now for school. Presently, I'm trying to break a commandLine entry which should be read     into four separate const char*.

```
        int state = 0;
        char *token = std::strtok(commandLine, " ");
        while(token != NULL)
             {
                     switch(state)
                    {
                            case 0: c = token; break;
                            case 1: u = token; break;                          
                            case 2: p = token;break;                        
                            case 3: a = token; break;            
                    }
                    token = std::strtok(NULL, " ");
                    state++;
             }

    const char* command = c.c_str();
    const char* user = u.c_str();
    const char* password = p.c_str();
    const char* args = a.c_str();
```

I realize that this isn't very well optimized; I've been trying a lot of different solutions because everything I've been trying has resulted in seg faults. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Parsing the command line is a solved problem: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/program_options.html

Comment: Sorry, for this project I'm not allowed to use boost. Otherwise this would be easier.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: Then use GNU Getopt: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

Comment: Any reason you can just use `std::string`?

Answer (score 0):

it's a intresting question ^_^! i try run this code in my computer, and i had the same problem when i define commandLine like this:

```
char* commandLine = "abc def ghi jkl";
```

the reason is the function strtok will change the string commandLine, part of the source code is:

```
 for ( ; *str ; str++ )
            if ( map[*str >> 3] & (1 << (*str & 7)) ) {
                    *str++ = '\0';
                    break;
            }
```

so, when i change my define to:

```
char commandLine[] = "abc def ghi jkl";
```

the problem is gone.wish userful to you, thanks~